# How to string PHP to URL on Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, string, get

My code:

```
var page = 1;
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            $('#more').hide();
            $('#no-more').hide();
            if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 200) {
                $('#more').css("top","400");
                $('#more').show();
            }
            if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
                $('#more').hide();
                $('#no-more').hide();
                page++;
                var data = {
                    page_num: page
                };
                var actual_count = "<?php echo $actual_row_count; ?>";
                if((page-1)* 2 > actual_count){
                    $('#no-more').css("top","400");
                    $('#no-more').show();
                }else{
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "search-data.php/?search=<?php echo $search ?>", // <---- Here Problem
                        data:data,
                        success: function(res) {
                            $("#result").append(res);
                            console.log(res);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

on the file `search-data.php`:

```
$search = $_GET['search']; // no string
```

Comment: from where you are getting this `$search`? is it have any value? Also check your browser console for errors, and change `$_GET['search']` to `$_POST['search']` because it's POST request

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is and/or what you want to do ...

Comment: does $search has value?

Comment: $search from main URL https://blackangker.com/?search=darla, this case i want to proces java to url proses on https://blackangker.com/search-data.php?search=darla on PHP file have string $_POST['page_num'] for Limit on mysql and $_POST['page_num'] from my javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your ajax request to GET

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "search-data.php/?search=<?php echo $search ?>",
    data:data,
    success: function(res) {
        $("#result").append(res);
        console.log(res);
    }
});
```

Thanks for your answer "Morteza"

```
 $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "search-data.php/?search=<?php echo $_GET['search'] ?>&page=+data.page_num",
       data:data,
       success: function(res) {
       $("#result").append(res);
       console.log(res);
                        }
                    });
```

Thankyou very much :D

Regard's

Grenz

Comment: thanks this work but in the case, i have 2 methode page_num on data use a POST for limit mysqli and "search" from url use GET for filter field on mysql,  like a infinite scroll

Comment: you can use this URL for paging and search: `search-data.php/?search=<?php echo $search ?>&page=<?= $page_num ?>`

Comment: <?= $page_num ?> in the javascript data  page++;
                var data = {
                    page_num: page
                };

Comment: you can use this `"search-data.php/?search=<?php echo $search ?>&page="+data.page_num`

Comment: Done yups hehehe

Answer (score 2):

its post request change to

```
$search = $_POST['search'];
```

or change in your script

```
$.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "search-data.php/?search=<?php echo $search ?>", // <---- Here Problem
                        data:data,
                        success: function(res) {
                            $("#result").append(res);
                            console.log(res);
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: $.ajax its ok but unlimited while

Comment: unlimited while?

Comment: https://blackangker.com/?search=darla <----- Check Reduce the browser screen for scroll bar
because ---> page_num: <--- for limit mysql not exist

Comment: Done, problematic on post and get and should use include php, which previously caused php script not running because using .js on head, Thank you Arun hehe you answer is true

Answer (score 0):

Either during your ajax call, use `type : 'get'` or in search-data.php use `$_POST` Superglobal to fetch the data.